# Find Duplicate with Complex aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i am new to SQL , i need your expertise to achieve below requirement . please help me .

I have two data Set : data set 1 :

```
id Item Amount 
1  apple 100
2  apple -100
3  apple  200
4  apple  -200
5  apple  100
```

Output Should be **null**

data Set 2 :

```
id Item Amount 
1  apple 100
2  apple -100
3  apple  200
4  apple  -200
5  apple  100
6 apple   100
```

output should be

```
id Item  Amount
 6 apple 100
```

**Functionality :**  for an item 'apple' i have paid 100(1) and due to some condition i have returned the apple to the shop owner  so i get back my money -100 (2),

again i buy  apple so amount will be 200(3)(Amount increased), again i return it so -200(4) .

finally i pay 100(5) and again buy apple .but this time the system is duplicating my final payment 100(5) as 100(6) .

i need to find if the system is duplicating my transaction or not and display the duplicated transaction

Comment: First of all you need a reliable criteria for dubles. What if you really buy 2 'apple 100'?

Comment: Fix the system which is duplicating, records should not be saved in the first place.

Comment: @Serg : I am buying one one apple . the cost will defer based on time .

Answer (score 0):

You would appear to want the last row when the number of positive amounts exceeds the number of negative amounts by more than 1:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by id desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1 and
      (select sum(case when amount > 0 then 1
                       when amount < 0 then -1
                  end)
       from t
      ) >= 2
```